# Editing armature in edit mode mess up pose mode

Tags: armature

As the title says when I change the imported motion capture armature, and than I edit it in the Edit mode to fit to the model (eg. moving the arms), it mess up the original animation: twist the arms.
I made parenting to the arm bones.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the blend file?

Comment: Here you can find it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23530152/armature.blend
I didn't apply anything to the armature.

Comment: Sorry, can't see what's wrong with it...

Comment: Is there any chance that the .bvh file is bad? I made it with iPi Soft.

Comment: I have no idea, I've never actually done such thing;   Looking at the website, it seems it supports Blender, so maybe try exporting directly to a blend file, but I doubt that works, if at all posible.

Answer (score 1):

You should not edit the bones in edit mode after animating them, do that only if you want to modify the rest pose.
If you want to pose the bones than use Pose mode. Editing bones after posing will break the pose because you have modified the original rest pose and the transformation matrices of all the bones would evaluate a wrong pose. because poses are relative to the Rest_Pose.

you need to setup your rest pose while in edit mode (or in pose mode and use  ***Apply Pose as Restpose***) and then proceed to posing the character, without modifying the rest pose.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4Sh2ky7l7k
I have a motion capture armature imported, and I have to "apply" the pose just like the model. And as the tutorial shows I should do that in Edit mode. Or should I do it other way?

Comment: could it be that you have applied the armature modifier before making the armature fit your model? This could be one reason, any later edit breaks the poses.

Comment: No. First I always import the armature, than the model, than I "fit" the armature to the model in edit mode. Finally I make the parenting. But if the model is not imported (so just the armature is in the .blend project) and than I make changes to the armature it messes up. Here is az example project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23530152/armature.blend Can you look at it?

Comment: Do you clear all transformations (Pose >> Clear Transformation >> All) before posing? (as he does in the video)... to bring the armature to the pivot point correctly?

Comment: Yes, I do that.

Comment: In the screenshot that you have above, the pivot point is by his feet... when i clear transformation, he goes down and the pivot point is located around his core... Make sure the pivot point is on the same place in edit and pose mode...?

Comment: Meanwhile I exported the .bvh from iPi Soft again, by new settings (no T-pose at the first frame, and resetting coordinate system). Now the pivot point is the same but no changes. I updated the project at dropbox with the new armature.

Comment: So did that fix it for you?

Comment: No, the distortion stays after the changes in edit mode. I'm starting to think that iPi Soft export the armature that way that I can't make changes to it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what else could it be, if I come up with anything I will write.